# How can I show my camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

I wrote a class for camera preview

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }


    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, Camera camera){
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation){
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        }else{
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        setCameraDisplayOrientation((Activity)getContext(), Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size bestSize = null;
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()){
            if (size.width <= i1 && size.height <=i2) {
                if (bestSize == null) {
                    bestSize = size;
                } else {
                    int bestArea = bestSize.width * bestSize.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > bestArea){
                        bestSize = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        parameters.setPictureSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

        try{
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }


}
```

And then I wrote a layout file and I want to display the preview in the "SurfaceView"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop_navigation"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@string/stop_navigation"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So how should I do in the main activity? Before I just did the below code and everything is fine.

```
CameraView cameraView = new CameraView(this);
addContentView(cameraView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But now I need to put the preview into the layout I design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

You need to Change in your **SurfaceView** in **XML** File.

Replace your surfaceView with this

```
<CameraView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view" />
```

and your remaining code is Right.let me know after change

Hope this will helps...(:

Comment: If I do this, I need to change my CameraView constructor like this: public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        ...
    } I am not sure what parameter should I pass for attributeSet in the main activities.

Comment: yes you are right..but you have to use one or more Constructor in your class.keep old Constructor as it is.and add new constructor with attributeSet.and finally use old Constructor in Main activity.

Comment: or if you want to working with a Custom camera using surfaceView then Follow this Link :- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/how-to-make-a-custom-camera-ion-android/

Comment: I add a new constructor in my CameraView class to deal with the problem of xml file, but I have no idea how should I do in the main activity. What's next of CameraView cameraView = new CameraView(this)?

Comment: see take your Camera_View in .xml file into Framelayout.And follow my steps.

Comment: Then the layout I designed is never used.

Comment: wait i am updating my answer.for few minutes you will only do as i will say.then after tell me what is wrong.OK.

Comment: ohh now i did see.You did not use an SurfaceView in your CameraView.without that how can you show Preview.

Comment: Please see this Example on Github.this is best for you and also seem same as your Example.
https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example/blob/master/src/com/example/cam/Preview.java

Answer (score 1):

```
Use FrameLayout and add CameraPreview to it.



// Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);


/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should add the camera permission in you `Manifest.xml` :

`android:name="android.permission.CAMERA`

And, add this in your activity :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCameraView.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mCameraView.stop();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Check this link, it's the easiest way to do it :
https://github.com/google/cameraview

Comment: I've done this, it's ok to show camera preview if I follow my previous work. But now I design a new layout, I need to show the preview in that layout.