# How to open the camera in videoView in Kotlin OR How to resize the camera width and height?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

Here is the sample of code

i want to show camera which looks like videocalling small camera
the camera size will be small such as in video calling app small camera

```
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {

        cameraIntent.putExtra(
            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        )  // Tested on API 24 Android version 7.0(Samsung S6)
    }

    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {

        cameraIntent.putExtra(
            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        ) // Tested on API 27 Android version 8.0(Nexus 6P)
        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true)
    }

    else -> cameraIntent.putExtra(
        "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
        1
    )  // Tested API 21 Android version 5.0.1(Samsung S4)
}

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 123)
```

Comment: You should try to explain in more detail what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. No one will write a complete app for you.

Comment: Sir i want to open that camera in videoview

Comment: I understand this. But there are a lot of (official) resources out there, for example [how to display a camera preview](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) and [how to control the camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect). Have you worked through those? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried these but didn't work for me

Comment: You could explain in more detail _what_ of the steps did not work.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586862/how-can-i-show-my-camera-preview/41588829)